# Is there a quick way to add work items with child links?

Tags: tfs

Each time we create a patch iteration, we have a number of specific activities we need to perform before we can release. These are typically under a story 'Release activities' and are child items such as 'Update Help Guide', 'Targeted Regression', 'Produce Changelog' etc...

What I'd like to do is have a template I can use where I can quickly create the parent story in the target iteration, and have the child items automatically created. Is this possible without using the API? Maybe via an extension? I could use Copy Work Item for the parent, but I'd still need to create all the children manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it`s possible with Excel ([Add linked backlog items and tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops#add-linked-backlog-items-and-tasks)). You can do next steps:

1. Create new excel sheet and connect to tfs.
2. Add needed child-parent levels.
3. Paste prepared work item structure.
4. Update the iteration path and any additional data.
5. Publish.

Comment: That worked pretty well, except the tasks are unparented in the iteration. How do I bind them to the parent?

Comment: @spikey_richie you can find useful tips here: [Useful tips when working with a tree list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops#useful-tips-when-working-with-a-tree-list). In excel: 1) you create your new US "Release activities"; 2) press "Add tree level" button 3) in "Title 2" column create child tasks 'Update Help Guide', 'Targeted Regression', 'Produce Changelog' etc...

Comment: @spikey_richie To link exiting work items to parent US in your excel list, you can press "Indent" button.